# Excel-VBA Convert columns based on separate table

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to utilize VBA to build a FX converter.

I have an excel file that I need to modify to convert amounts from local currency to USD.  The amounts are loaded in each column by customer currency by month (each month has a column).   What can be done in VBA to go through the FX table by month, and convert the times based on time and currency.

```
CAD EUR AUD JPY USD GBP
```

1   0.76115 1.06925 0.7549  0.00868395  1   1.2551
2   0.74658 1.0598  0.75855 0.0087677   1   1.22775
3   0.75259 1.06795 0.74647 0.00898352  1   1.2532
4   0.73212 1.08985 0.7489  0.00897586  1   1.29535
5   0.74102 1.1277  0.74365 0.00905264  1   1.28795
6   0.7711  1.1419  0.76795 0.0088881   1   1.3017
7   0.80399 1.17565 0.7986  0.009042    1   1.3139
8   0.8071  1.1864  0.79685 0.00906824  1   1.29535
9   0.80212 1.1812  0.7842  0.0088573   1   1.3405
10  0.77851 1.1599  0.7669  0.00878735  1   1.31245
11  0.77851 1.1599  0.7669  0.00878735  1   1.31245
12  0.77851 1.1599  0.7669  0.00878735  1   1.31245

Client  Country Currency    Type    Product 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  Total
Company A   US  USD     Widget 1     10,000          5,000       533         1,000           5,200       1,000   22,733 
Company B   Spain   EUR     Widget 2         20,000                  5,000           3,000           100    28100
Company C   Italy   EUR     Widget 3     11,000              6,000               1,000           200     1,500  19700
Company D   Brazil  GBP     Widget 4                     5,000           1,000   121         200        6321

Apologies for the text.

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMHNo.png)
[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6JB0.png)

Comment: This would be better if instead of pictures you posted the data as text so we do not need to retype, we could then just copy and paste.

Comment: @ScottCraner Not sure how to do that.  Is there away for me to attach my excel files?

Comment: put it in as text and someone will help format it.